# Use polkadot-v0.9.33 or hight verison bianry launch local parachain onborading fails

Tags: polkadot-js, parachain

Using the ts code to call the `parasSudoWrapper.sudoScheduleParaInitialize` interface to register the parachain locally, the parachain has not produced blocks.. It is only a parathread found in the polkadot.js UI. I need to manually call `slots.froceLease` on the UI interface to renew the slot lease, and the parathread can be used Upgrade to parachain. However, calling the `parasSudoWrapper.sudoScheduleParaInitialize` directly on the polkadot-js UI interface can successfully register the parachain and work normally.
But using polkadot-v0.9.32 or previous versions, there is no such problem.

BTW I found that other parachain teams also introduced slots.frocelease in their own polkadot-launch.
for example:

- https://github.com/AXIA-DEV/launcher/blob/7e0e1f78eadc8fa004529fec20a8c885cad99f6a/launch/src/rpc.ts#L95
- https://github.com/mangata-finance/mangata-node/commit/0f202986f112d8dc2a70d09c2733461af47cef04
- https://github.com/tolak/khala-parachain-dev/blob/f456c273867e392bb4801680159e7ac074b177b0/polkadot-launch/src/rpc.ts#L92

Related issue https://github.com/litentry/litentry-parachain/issues/1097.

Hope you can answer my question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I‘m on 0.9.33 and 0.9.36. Both works for me.

Did you change this to `Yes`?

[image]

Comment: I used ts-code to do this https://github.com/litentry/litentry-parachain/blob/dev/ts-tests/tests/register-parathread.ts, But just registering as a parathread does not become a parachain.

Comment: Code LGTM. Maybe you need to bump the deps version? I'm not sure.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention polkadot-js version v9.11.1